# How can I use observer to export a plot?

Tags: r, pdf-generation, shiny

I have made a small app to attempt to learn to export plots to a file using shiny.  At the moment I am trying to use observer, and I have successfully exported plots, but not in the way I would like to.  For the most part I made this app copying the observer demo from the shiny gallery, and updating to try to do pdfs.  The UI just has two action buttons (input$ex, and input$plot), and a slider to change sample size.  It outputs a plot of two random normals against each other.  I tried to get the plots to output using the following code.

```
pdf.check<-reactive({
    #'this should change when you hit the plot button, or when you change the sample size,
    #'but not when you hit the export button. Whenever you hit the export button
    #'pdf.check!=input$ex
    input$n
    input$plot
    isolate({input$ex})
  })
  obs <- observer({
    if(input$ex>0 & input$ex!=isolate({pdf.check()})){
      #'when you hit the export button, this should start a pdf.  it shouldn't do it
      #'for any other input, or when you open the app
      pdf(file=logfilename, width=6, height = 5)
    }
    #'I included the input$plot to make this run whenever you hit the plot button, and
    #'it should just be making these graphs.
    input$plot
    #'isolated input$n so this code doesn't run when you change n
    isolate({plot(rnorm(input$n), rnorm(input$n), pch=20, xlab="X", ylab = "Y", main= input$plot)})

  })
```

What this actually does is export to a pdf every time I hit the plot button, but it won't export anymore after I move the n slider.  Also, if I have already moved the n slider, I have to hit the export button twice to start the pdf.  I do not know enough about the observer to know what I have done wrong.

One other problem I'm having is that I can't get the app to run `dev.off()` when it closes.  I can include something to manually run `dev.off()`, but if someone accidentally closes the app without doing that, I'd like the pdf to still close.  I attempted to use the following.

```
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    dev.off()
    unlink(logfilename)
  })
```

Honestly I am still pretty inexperienced with observer, and I am not entirely sure I understand how it functions.  Any help that can be given would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is wrap your plot functions within the download handler rather than in your data.  Something like this, where observer() is the function to create a plot:

```
output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {paste0(input$plot, ".pdf")},
    content = function(file) {
      pdf(file, width=8.5, height=5)
      observer()
      dev.off()      
    })
```

Then back in the ui, you can add a button for downloading the plot (different than just displaying the plot on the screen).

```
downloadButton("downloadPlot", label="Download Plot")
```

Comment: I have successfully been able to download single plots using the download handler before.  What I want to do here is download one file containing many plots, similar to how the `pdf()` function works in the regular R console.  I am going to try this now, but I am worried I will only get one plot at a time.

Comment: edit: I just understood the observer being a function thing and felt like an idiot.  This should work, I just need to come up with some sort of way to quickly reproduce all the plots my function has made.